# Create Docker Network in docker-compose.yml or dockerfile

Tags: docker-compose, containers, dockerfile, docker-network

My docker services require a network to work properly. I intend to share my compose file, but I don't want to manually create the network with the right parameters each time.

I would like the network to be created during the build process, in the Dockerfile or in the docker-compose file.

Comment: did you know that docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose.yml servicename  will create a network by default. requires version 3.0 of docker-compose

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. It won't really help me though because I need a network with external access to get to some of my services. Using the container name/image to access my services is not working at all in the app, which is why I created the network.

Comment: The ip of the swarm manager is accessible from outside and will route the port to the container on the worker nodes.  So, you can just give the one ip to rule them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can create a network in your `Dockerfile`, but you can do so in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Have you looked at networking in Docker Compose?

You can specify your own networks with the `networks` key in your `docker-compose.yml` file. This lets you create custom networks and specify custom network drivers and options.

Each service in your `docker-compose.yml` file can specify what networks to connect to, with the service level `networks` key.

Here is an example from the [Compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks)

```
version: "3"
services:
  proxy:
    build: ./proxy
    networks:
      - frontend
  app:
    build: ./app
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  frontend:
    # Use a custom driver
    driver: custom-driver-1
  backend:
    # Use a custom driver which takes special options
    driver: custom-driver-2
    driver_opts:
      foo: "1"
      bar: "2"
```